# Shared module is not available for eager consumption - Angular 13

Tags: angular, webpack

I've read other answers and haven't had any success implementing federated modules with Angular 13.  I always get the 'Shared module is not available for eager consumption' message.

> TL;DR:
>
> 1. Double-check your public path in your custom webpack config - it may be missing a trailing `/` which WebPack may erroneously be reporting as "unavailable for eager consumption".
> 2. Check the routing - your MFE/remote module will receive the child routes *after* the host module's routing (so if your host is routing to the MFE when hitting the route 'login', your MFE will *not* get the 'login' path, it will get an empty path (see update 2 below).
> 3. Bootstrapping (update 1 below) may (or may not) be required.

Host App webpack.config.ts:

```
export const webpackConfig: Configuration = {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:4200',
    uniqueName: 'host',
  },
  plugins: {
    new container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "host",
      remotes: {
        "remote-login": "login@http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js"
      }
      shared: [
        "@angular/core",
        "@angular/common",
        "@angular/router",
        "@angular/common/http",
      ]
    })
  ]
}

export default webpackConfig;
```

The remote app:

```
export const webpackConfig: Configuration = {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:4201',
  },
  optimization: { runtimeChunk: false },
  experiments: { outputModule: true },
  plugins: {
    new container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "login",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        LoginComponent: './projects/module1/src/app/pages/login/login.component.ts',
      },
      shared: [
        "@angular/core",
        "@angular/common",
        "@angular/router",
        "@angular/common/http",
      ]
    })
  ]
}

export default webpackConfig;
```

#### Update 1:

I've tried using a 'bootstrap' file.  Using this in the `main.ts` file: `import('bootstrap').catch(err => console.error(err))` and now see the following error in the console - which appears solely related to the new bootstrap process:
`ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk projects_host_src_bootstrap_ts failed.`

_Note: This error was because the public path defined in the webpack.config.ts was missing a trailing slash.  Leading it to try to load the chunk from `http://localhost:4200projets_host_src_bootstrap_ts` (missing the `/` after the port number).

#### Update 2:

I'm now getting `Error: ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule 'LoginComponent' is not a subtype of NgModuleType.`  So at least I'm back in 'Angular-error-land'.

I had to set the routes in the LoginModule (home of the LoginComponent) to be:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', //Note: empty path, _not_ matching the app's 'login' path
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.component').then(m => m.LoginComponent),
  }
]
```

#### Update 3: It's working

So I changed the MFE (the LoginModule) routing to be non-lazy and it worked!

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', //Note: empty path, _not_ matching the app's 'login' path
    component: LoginComponent,
  }
]
```

I'm going to roll back the bootstrap changes and see if they are required, but it's at least using the federated module now!

Comment: Why do you need eager in the first place?

Comment: I guess I never questioned it.  I saw it in a solution and started using it...  I'll remove it and give it a shot!  (Edit: Ok, tried removing eager, same error)

Comment: Strange. Did you delay bootstrapping using a bootstrap file that imports main.ts as well?

Comment: Is the 'native' bootstrapping in Angular enough?  I know in React you need/should have that layer of bootstrapping, I assumed that Angular's NgModule Bootstrap property would be equivalent?

Comment: I think it’s needed in Angular as well to allow webpack to configure its thing..

Comment: Well, now I'm getting a new error (see Update above).

Comment: Ok, that was a missing trailing slash on the public path... getting closer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Double-check your public path in your custom webpack config - it may be missing a trailing / which WebPack may erroneously be reporting as "unavailable for eager consumption".
2. Check the routing - your MFE/remote module will receive the child routes after the host module's routing (so if your host is routing to the MFE when hitting the route 'login', your MFE will not get the 'login' path, it will get an empty path.
3. Bootstrapping may (or may not) be required.

Answer (score 11):

To the original error message, there's a [Webpack doc on this specific error](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#uncaught-error-shared-module-is-not-available-for-eager-consumption).

In short, you need an async boundary (which is created by the existence of files `bootstrap.js` + `index.js`) that ensure shared dependencies are awaited when loaded on the client side:

`index.js`:

```js
import('./bootstrap.js');
```

`bootstrap.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

// ... the rest of application root component
```

You could also add `eager: true` to the shared dependencies, but this will add them to the initial chunk regardless if they are used.

Comment: for me this doesn't help, the error just starts to point to the bootstrap.js file

Comment: this is angular app, not a react app. associate answer in relation to correct code base.

Answer (score 2):

I migrated my nx angular 14 app to webpack federation, and just moved the original `main.ts` content to the new file `bootstrap.ts` and update `main.ts` to:

```
import('./bootstrap').catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

and it's working!

Answer (score 1):

for me starting Angular with

```
ng serve --hmr
```

seemed to be the problem. Remove hot module reloading removed the error.

Comment: I added "hmr": true to my project.json config and got this error also. Removing it fixed it, but that doesn't make sense why this causes a module error. Any ideas?